# tensorflow.js drawing heart using webgl

Tags: math, webgl, tensorflow.js

Trying to display a heart by using the formula [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_symbol#Parametrisation)

```
 (x²+y²−r²)³−rx²y³=0
```

The inside of the heart should follow the formula:

```
(x²+y²−r²)³−rx²y³<0
```

But currently only half of the heart is displayed

```js
class Heart {
    variableNames = ["X"];
    outputShape;
    userCode;

    constructor(shape) {
        this.outputShape = shape;
        const [h, w] = shape;
        this.userCode = `
      void main() {
        ivec3 coords = getOutputCoords();
        

        float x = float(-coords[0] + ${h} / 2);
        float y = float(-coords[1] + ${w} / 2);
        float a = 100.0;

        float x2 = x * x ;
        float y2 = y * y ;

        float x3 = x2 * x;
        float y3 = y2 * y;
        

        // float val = pow(x2 + y2 - 8120.0, 3.0);
        // float val = (x2 + 9.0*y2/4.0 - 1000.0, 3.0) * (x2 + 9.0*y2/4.0 - 1000.0, 3.0) * (x2 + 9.0*y2/4.0 - 1000.0, 3.0);
        float val = pow(x2 + y2 - a*a, 3.0) - x3*y2*a;
        // float val = x2 + y2 - 1000000.0;

        int r = coords[0];
        int c = coords[1];
        int d = coords[2];

        if(val < 0.0) {
            setOutput(255.0);
            // setOutput(float((getX(r, c, 0) + getX(r, c, 1) + getX(r, c, 2)) / 3.0));
            // if(coords[2] == 0) {
            //     setOutput(float((getX(r, c, d) + getX(r, c, d + 1) + getX(r, c, d + 2)) / 3.0));
            // } else if(coords[2] == 1) {
            //     setOutput(float((getX(r, c, d - 1) + getX(r, c, d) + getX(r, c, d + 1)) / 3.0));
            // } else {
            //     setOutput(float((getX(r, c, d) + getX(r, c, d - 1) + getX(r, c, d - 2)) / 3.0));
            // }
        } else {

            setOutput(getX(r, c, d));
        }

      }
    `;
    }
}


const tensor = tf.ones([400, 300, 3]).cast('int32');
    console.log(tensor.shape);
    /////////////////
    const prog = new Heart(tensor.shape);
    const drawn = tf.backend().compileAndRun(prog, [tensor])
    console.log(drawn);
    const canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
    // canvas1.width = 400;
    tf.browser.toPixels(drawn, canvas1);
    console.log(canvas1.width);
    canvas1.width = 800;
    document.body.append(canvas1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can use `(x<sup>2</sup>+y<sup>2</sup>−r<sup>2</sup>)<sup>3</sup>−rx<sup>2</sup>y<sup>2</sup>=0 ` instead of x2, r2,etc. I tried to edit but it's showing errors.

Comment: Secondly, you are right in assuming (x2+y2−r2)3−rx2y3 < 0 shows the inner part. Here is a demonstration: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/y7qnxymx0n Also note, you can modify the equations at your discretion and test them out too.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The issue was related to the use of the function `pow` leading to undefined behavior. Please see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pow(x, y)`, there is an undefined behavior when x<0 or if x=0 and y≤0 according to the [doc](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/pow.xhtml).

To solve it, the explicit multiplication should be used:

```
float val = (x*x + y*y - a*a) * (x*x + y*y - a*a) * (x*x + y*y - a*a) - x*x*x*y*y*a;
```

Comment: i tried your example and i don't get an undefined behaviour. i can see the whole heart drawn in the canvas. I uploaded the example on github https://github.com/kalwalt/tsfjs-sketches/blob/master/heart/heart.html can you confirm? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe it is browser related. But i was having an issue with the power formula

Comment: Ok, thank you, do you remember which browser you used?

Comment: I am a Chrome evangelist. Surely it was Chrome, but can't remember the version. But as the doc said, the result is undefined; which means it can or not work. The behavior is just undefined. But I now see that the code of the question is working